# Skipping text while reading files in C++

Tags: c++, file

I'm learning C++, and I'm doing work with data loaded from external text files using `cin`.

I'm trying to recognize certain strings in large amounts of data that I need to skip through.

How would I write a function that skips through a certain number of characters in a file / on a line, either as I'm importing them from a file? Does such a thing already exist in iostream or similar?

Google has let me down so far.

Comment: What do you mean by skipping text is it like 10 characters on each line, or something like skip "foo" ?

Comment: How are you reading the file in? If you're just using fopen or something, a simple `buf += 10' will skip ten characters or whatever.

Comment: This is tagged C++, you best not be using fopen and buffers. Adding to a buffer pointer like that isn't terribly safe anyway.

Comment: You should probably tell us what your input and 'grammar'/'pattern recognition' looks like. It is very hard to give optimization advice on generic usecases: you'll just end up with generic algorithms and they are never optimized for your specific case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On general skipping: [seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/)

On the real issue:

It seems like you would want to be matching patterns against a large body of (semi?) text. Since the pattern is long enough that you can gain from skipping input stretches, it *really* seems you are trying to invent optimized string search all over.

It has been done:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer_Moore_string_search_algorithm
- http://volnitsky.com/project/str_search/index.html

Implementations exist in the wild (I assume Boost String Algorithm should have it... but maybe it too general-purpose to have it. I'd have a look anyways)

### PS.: Boost Spirit

This parser is currently reviewing an enhancement that implements the `qi::seek[]` directive:

- https://github.com/jamboree/boost-jamboree-spirit/blob/master/libs/spirit/repository/example/qi/seek.cpp
- http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Proposal-for-qi-seek-directive-td3830251.html

This allows blazingly fast skipping inside a Spirit grammar. So if you have a case for a full parser (perhaps even scanner/parser), Spirit Qi could really be your match in performance.

Be sure to:

- avoid buffering input iterator adaptors if you can (depends on grammar)
- imbue "C" locale if you can
- operate on the input streambuf's iterators as opposed to input streams iterators

Comment: I added references to Spirit parsing framework as it might be relevant (depending on your input format)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::ifstream;
using std::string;
using std::getline;

ifstream ifs(filename);
if ( ! ifs ) {
    /* ERROR CODE IN HERE */
}

string line;
while ( getline(ifs, line) )
{
    // line now contains one line from the input file
    if ( /* want to skip */ ) {
        continue;
    }

    /* Do something with the line */
}
```

edit: some of the boost string predicates (starts_with, ends_with) might be useful for that conditional inside the while loop. For instance, if you only want to process lines that start with 'FOO', you would write

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
using boost::starts_with;

while ( getline(ifs,line) )
{
    if ( starts_with(line, "FOO") ) {
        /* DO SOMETHING */
    }
}
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/string_algo.html